# How do I animate a number in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I want to animate a number. The animation I want to achieve is going from 0 increasing all the way up to the current number (at high speed). In this project, the number is the number of steps a user has taken. Is there a way this can be achieved?

```
      LazyVStack{


            ForEach(steps, id: \.id) { step in

//Here is the number I want to be animated

                    Text("\(step.count)")
                        .font(.custom(customFont, size: 50))



                        Text("Steps")
                            .font(.custom(customFont, size: 25))
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
        }
    }
```

I believe I have a function along the right lines, I just need to apply it! Here is the function:

```
   func addNumberWithRollingAnimation() {
            withAnimation {
                // Decide on the number of animation tasks
                let animationDuration = 1000 // milliseconds
                let tasks = min(abs(self.enteredNumber), 100)
                let taskDuration = (animationDuration / tasks)
                
                // add the remainder of our entered num from the steps
                total += self.enteredNumber % tasks
                // For each task
                (0..<tasks).forEach { task in
                    // create the period of time when we want to update the number
                    // I chose to run the animation over a second
                    let updateTimeInterval = DispatchTimeInterval.milliseconds(task * taskDuration)
                    let deadline = DispatchTime.now() + updateTimeInterval
                    
                    // tell dispatch queue to run task after the deadline
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: deadline) {
                        // Add piece of the entire entered number to our total
                        self.total += Int(self.enteredNumber / tasks)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: You mean like this? https://www.dropbox.com/s/rmyv1v3czrwrdtb/animateNumber.mov?dl=0

Comment: Actually it is not clear what kind of animation and under which conditions you want to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a utility function called `Timer.animateNumber()` which takes a `Binding<Int>` to animate, a `Binding<Bool> busy` which indicates if the value is currently animating, and `Int start` value, an `Int end` value, and a `Double duration` in seconds.

To use it, you need to define an `@State private var number: Int` to animate, and `@State private var busy: Bool` to keep track of the animation's state.  This can also be used to terminate the animation early by just setting `busy` to `false`.  Pass in your `start` value, `end` value, and `duration` in seconds.

This demo shows two animated numbers.  The first counts up from 1 to 10000 in 1 second.  The second counts down from 20 to 0 in 20 seconds.  The `Stop All` button can be used to stop both animations.

```
extension Timer {
    static func animateNumber(number: Binding<Int>, busy: Binding<Bool>, start: Int, end: Int, duration: Double = 1.0) {
        busy.wrappedValue = true
        let startTime = Date()
        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1/120, repeats: true) { timer in
            let now = Date()
            let interval = now.timeIntervalSince(startTime)
            if !busy.wrappedValue {
                timer.invalidate()
            }
            if interval >= duration {
                number.wrappedValue = end
                timer.invalidate()
                busy.wrappedValue = false
            } else {
                number.wrappedValue = start + Int(Double(end - start)*(interval/duration))
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var number: Int = 0
    @State private var number2: Int = 0
    @State private var busy: Bool = false
    @State private var busy2: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 20) {
            Text(String(number))
            Button("Go") {
                if !busy {
                    Timer.animateNumber(number: $number, busy: $busy, start: 1, end: 10000, duration: 1)
                }
            }
            Text(String(number2))
            Button("Go") {
                if !busy2 {
                    Timer.animateNumber(number: $number2, busy: $busy2, start: 20, end: 0, duration: 20)
                }
            }
            Button("Stop All") {
                busy = false
                busy2 = false
            }
        }
    }
}
```