# Swiftui fast smooth change in the value of a variable over time

Tags: swift, variables, swiftui, volume

Is it possible to make it so that when the button is pressed, the variable can smoothly change its value from 0 to 1 within, for example, 0.01 seconds? This is required so that there are no clicks when changing the sound volume.

```
struct ContentView: View {

@State var volume:Float = 0

var body: some View {
    VStack(spacing: 50) {
        
        Text("\(volume)")
        
        Button("1") {
            volume = 1
    
        }
        
        Button("0") {
            volume = 0
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I animate a number in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73263935/how-do-i-animate-a-number-in-swift)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
struct ContentView: View {

let timer = Timer.publish(every: 0.001, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()

@State var toggle = false

@State var count:CGFloat = 0

var body: some View {
    
    VStack(spacing: 50) {
        
        Button("ON") {
            toggle = true
        }
        
        Button("OFF") {
            toggle = false
        }
        
        Text("\(count)")
            .font(.largeTitle)
          
    }
    .onReceive(timer, perform: { _ in
        if toggle == true && count < 1 {
            count += 0.01
        } else if toggle == false && count > 0 {
            count -= 0.01
        }
        
    })
   
}
```

}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).